# $\lim \frac{n}{n^2+1}$ as n goes to infinity.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> Find $\lim \frac{n}{n^2+1}$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

For $\epsilon > 0$, let $N = 1/\epsilon.$ Then $n > N$ implies $n > 1/\epsilon$ which implies $ \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon. $ But $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{n}{n^2} > \frac{n}{n^2+1}.$ Therefore $\frac{n}{n^2+1} < \epsilon, $ so $\bigg| \frac{n}{n^2+1} -0 \bigg|< \epsilon. $

Is the above correct?

Comment: Looks solid to me. (The conclusion, of course, is that $\lim n/(n^2+1) = 0$.)

Comment: Nice question! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. I would like to provide another arrangement of proof for your reference, which would look more "natural":

If $n \geq 1$, then 
$$
\frac{n}{n^{2}+1} < \frac{1}{n};
$$
given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$ if $n > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$;
hence taking $N := \lceil 1/\varepsilon \rceil + 1$ suffices.